# C++ std::getline error

Tags: c++, getline

I'm new to C++, could someone please explain to me why I received the below errors when I do use "std::getline"?  Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

  string name;  //receive an error here

  std::cout << "Enter your entire name (first and last)." << endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, name);

  std::cout << "Your full name is " << name << endl;

  return 0;
}


ERRORS:
te.cc: In function `int main()':
te.cc:7: error: `string' was not declared in this scope
te.cc:7: error: expected `;' before "name"
te.cc:11: error: `endl' was not declared in this scope
te.cc:12: error: `name' was not declared in this scope
```

However, the program would run and compile when I used "getline" with "using namespace std;" instead of std::getline.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string name;

  cout << "Enter your entire name (first and last)." << endl;
  getline(cin, name);

  cout << "Your full name is " << name << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The errors are not from `std::getline`.  The error is you need to use `std::string` unless you use the `using namespace std`.  Also would need `std::endl`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `std::` on all the identifiers from that namespace. In this case, `std::string` and `std::endl`.  You can get away without it on `getline()`, since Koenig lookup takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string name;  // note the std::

    std::cout << "Enter your entire name (first and last)." << std::endl; // same here
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cout << "Your full name is " << name << std::endl; // and again

    return 0;
}
```

You just needed to state the namespace for various elements that are in the `std` namespace (alternatively, you can remove all the `std::`s and place a `using namespace std;` line after your includes.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
     std::string name; 

      std::cout << "Enter your entire name (first and last)." << 
      std::endl;

      while(getline(std::cin, name))
      {
            std::cout <<"Your name is:"<< name << '\n';
     }

  return 0;
}
```